# What are good ways to check valid user input for multiple items in C++? Not std::cin >> x >> y >> z;, but input throughout the program

Tags: c++, input

I've been looking everywhere for this answer and I am having a hard time finding a "Right answer" per say. I want something to take with me for basic console programs in the future, reprompting the user until they enter the right variable type. **This would preferably be something that can be used across all parts (main, other cpp files) of the program to prevent repetition.**

I'm still learning, so I see words like "boilerplate code" and advice saying not to repeat myself thrown around, and it makes me nervous to do something that might be a bad habit to take into the field in the future. Then again, I might just be overcomplicating things!

Here's some pseudocode to describe my question.

```
#include "RandClass.h"

int main() {
    // Random int
    
    /* 
       **ASK USER INPUT**
       **CHECK INPUT FOR INT USING FUNC**
    */

    // More random blocks of code
    
    /* 
       **ASK USER INPUT**
       **CHECK INPUT FOR INT USING FUNC**
    */

    // So on, so forth
}

// RandClass CPP file

#include "RandClass.h"

void RandClass::randomMutatorFunc() {
    /* 
       **ASK USER INPUT**
       **CHECK INPUT FOR INT USING FUNC**
    */
}
```

I have looked around on Reddit, here, and very sparingly at other random examples. If there is a function that I could use across all of my classes that isn't considered bad practice, that would be wonderful. But again, things like abstraction/encapsulation keep getting drilled into my head and I don't want to learn bad habits.

And if there are great libraries you recommend, I am all ears!

Apologies if this isn't a good question, I haven't had much luck, and the amount of information can be overwhelming at times.

Comment: Do you know how to do user input & validation? What's stopping you from turning it into a function?

Comment: You can make a `.h` file, define that function, and then include that header in all your `.cpp` files where you wish to use it. Design is totally up to you.

Comment: Nothing wrong with writing a `get_valid_int` free function that gets an input from the user, confirms that its an `int` and, optionally, that the value is inside a valid range. In some cases you cold abstract it with a template to cover most numeric types, and that should be all the abstraction you need.

Comment: But remember to think in building blocks. It may be beneficial to implement the `get_int` and the `is_valid` portions in separate functions and have a `get_valid_int` wrapper function that calls both functions. The user calls `get_int` when they have unusual-or-no verifification requirements, otherwise they call `get_valid_int`.

Comment: @ChrisMM I think I'm just overthinking the whole abstraction thing

Comment: @underloaded_operator Thank you and to the user below you. I will look into trying these and practicing.

Comment: @user4581301 Probably with the ears `:)`

Comment: What may be confusing about the different kinds of advice you read, is that the answer to this question depends a lot on the scope of your project. If it's a straight forward 200 LOC console tool, a quick function might do all you need. For some something more complex, you might need something more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good question.

Usually, I proceed like this:

- write the code once (in your case, the code would be reading an integer and validating it).
- if the code is required in multiple places, extract the code into a separate function, put in in a cpp file and add a declaration in a header file.
- reuse the code by calling the function wherever it is necessary.